# Using ASIHTTPRequest and json-framework on the iPhone

Tags: iphone

I'm planning on using both these libraries (or wrappers?) in my upcoming iPhone app. I see one of the top reason applications get refused, is due to using private frameworks/API calls. Is ASIHTTPRequest and json-framework considered such, or can I safely use these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when people say "private frameworks" they mean pieces of Apple's iPhone OS that are undocumented.  Due to the way Objective C works, you can call undocumented OS methods by name, and Apple tends to frown on that.

Using 3rd party libraries like ASIHTTPRequest is not a problem, unless, like Joe Hewitt's Three20 library, the library itself uses undocumented OS calls.